# Password visibility icon using fontawesome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this login form:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="${postUrl ?: '/login/authenticate'}" method="POST" id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="${usernameParameter ?: 'username'}" id="username" autocapitalize="none"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="${passwordParameter ?: 'password'}" id="password"/>
      <i id="passwordToggler" title="toggle password display" onclick="passwordDisplayToggle()"> &#128065</i>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
         <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="${rememberMeParameter ?: 'remember-me'}" id="remember_me" 
         <g:if test='${hasCookie}'>checked="checked"</g:if>
         /> Remember me
      </label>
   </div>
   <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Currently it using an eye emoji like this:
[image]

But I want to change it to font awesome fa-eye also currently when I click on reveal password it showing cross sign and I also want to change that to eye lash icon as well.
Right now the eye and the cross sign icon I use unicode to display it.
Here is my javascript code:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        document.forms['loginForm'].elements['username'].focus();
    });
    function passwordDisplayToggle() {
        var toggleEl = document.getElementById("passwordToggler");
        var eyeIcon = '\u{1F33D}';
        var xIcon = '\u{2715}';
        var passEl = document.getElementById("password");
        if (passEl.type === "password") {
            toggleEl.innerHTML = xIcon;
            passEl.type = "text";
        } else {
            toggleEl.innerHTML = eyeIcon;
            passEl.type = "password";
        }
    }
```

Any idea how I can switch it to font-awesome fa-eye?
Many thanks

Comment: This does not seem related to the Grails and totally dependent on the JQuery or any other JS Library you may want to use for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to replace it with this jquery code to make it work :

```
    function passwordDisplayToggle() {

        var passEl = document.getElementById("password");
        var passToggler=$('#passwordToggler');

        if (passEl.type === "password") {
            passEl.type = "text";
            passToggler.removeClass('fa-eye');
            passToggler.addClass('fa-eye-slash');
        } else {
            passToggler.removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
            passToggler.addClass('fa-eye');
            // passToggler.addClass('d-none');
            passEl.type = "password";
        }
    }
```